# How to dynamically configure Passportjs strategies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am playing around with passport, and configuring my twitter login this way:

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: '*****',
    consumerSecret: '*****',
    callbackURL: "http://blabla/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    done(null, profile)
  }
));
```

I want to be able to configure this values: (consumerKey, consumerSecret, callbackURL) on runtime, based on the logged user. That is, each user will have their on Twitter app that they need to register with Twitter.

Any advice?

Comment: do you have multiple api key/secrets for twitter?

Comment: I also have a similar problem in which I have a single app that is multi-tenant and thus connects to multiple google, facebook, twitter apps.

Comment: @onuriltan: I'm assuming that is the case, each user would have it's own key/secret pair.

Comment: Twitter consumer key/secret that you give to the TwitterStrategy constructor are not belong to users, they are belong to you for authenticating twitter users and the profile object that is the argument of the callback is what matters, so it is fine just using your consumer key/secret in my opinion. What do you mean by you have multiple tenants in the app, you have multiple Twitter Apps for a specific case?

Comment: Yes, the case I have and the case that's described in the question is when you have multiple Twitter apps. For example, the same node app is a CMS that serves Linux.com and freebsd.com and people can log in to either and each have their own Twitter App. Pretty normal multi tenant.

Comment: @pupeno I think your case is a bit different. You have a known amount of key/secret pair right? But I still don't quite get how you would separate your app. In case of the Linux.com and freebsd.com they're probably separate instances and doesn't necessarily have to load the key/secret dynamically. What about your case how would you know which set of key/secret pair to use? Are the authentication path different?

Comment: What I don't understand is that user is not logged-in yet, so how can you understand a user needs to be authenticated from another twitter app without logging in him/her? I mean is there a parameter that determines this situation before login?

Comment: @thammada.ts: they are not known at start time, they come from the database, and they can vary over time. Some comes to awesomecms.com, signs up for an account, specifies that their domain is linux.com, enter their twitter id and key, and that's how users log in at linux.com to leave comments (for example). Very usual multi-tenant application. Then someone else comes and signs up at awesomecms.com and does the same thing for freebsd.com and so on. The same running instance serves all those domains and it uses the domain name to select which tenant, content, and oauth credentials to use.

Comment: @onuriltan: this is a multi-tenant application, the owner of a company signs up to provide a service to their customers. For example, the owner of linux.com signs up to awesomecms.com (using awesomecms.com twitter app), and then configures the app to respond to linux.com, and enter the twitter credentials for their own app, so when the customers signing up at linux.com, they only see linux.com's twitter app. It's a B2B2C multi-tenant application.

Comment: Thank you @pupeno now you question is clear enough, I'll provide you something when I have time enough, I'll refer to the names of your previous comment

Answer (score 15):

Instead of registering a strategy ahead-of-time with `passport.use()`, the strategy can be passed directly to `authenticate()` (as opposed to passing the strategy name).

For example:

```
function login(req, res, next) {
  var user = req.user;
  var consumerKey = getConsumerKeyForUser(user);
  // Create a strategy instance specifically for this user.
  var strategy = new TwitterStrategy({ consumerKey: consumerKey }, ...);
  // Authenticate using the user-specific strategy
  passport.authenticate(strategy)(req, res, next);
}
```

More information on this technique can be found here: https://medium.com/passportjs/authenticate-using-strategy-instances-49e58d96ec8c

Comment: This seems to be working. The type for that function in TypeScript don't accept a strategy, so, I'll file a bug report for that.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use **your** consumer key and consumer secret, not the ones of your users. Then your application will be able to authenticate **your users** using Twitter. But those keys and secrets are used to authenticate your app to the Twitter API.

See this example project:

- https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-twitter-example

Comment: It is not what I am asking, it is not a normal application, is a proxy for authenticate various apps. I want every user to be able to provide its secret/appId and use them. I know how it works in the case of authenticate users for my app.

Comment: @ciaoben Then just use values provided by your users as the arguments to the TwitterStrategy constructor. Just keep in mind that you will need to keep one TwitterStrategy object and one instance of the passport middleware per your customer. They would need to give you those values and I expect this to be the hardest part. Make sure that it's not against the Twitter API TOC.